# Foreach dentro de foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Preciso executar um `foreach` dentro de outro `foreach` no PHP. Porém ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH
>   <sup>se referindo à linha onde ocorre o segundo foreach.</sup>

Segue parte do código:

```
$select = $bd -> prepare("SELECT * FROM umatabela ORDER BY id DESC");
$select -> execute();
$Fetch = $select -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$Conta = $select -> rowCount();

if ($Conta) {
  foreach ($Fetch as $postagem) {
    $oilUser = $postagem["sla"];

    $selectFoto = $bd->prepare("SELECT foto FROM outratabela WHERE cond='$oilUser' LIMIT 1");
    $selectFoto -> execute();
    $FetchFoto = $selectFoto -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "
    <a href='#'>".foreach($FetchFoto as $autorFoto) {
    echo "<img src='".$autorFoto["foto"]."' alt='".$postagem["autor"]."' class='img-circulo'>";
    }."</a>
  }
}
```

Como posso resolver isso? Lembrando que, preciso fazer as consultas em 2 tabelas diferentes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você não pode concatener um `foreach` com uma string como tentou fazer. Precisa separar as coisas:

```
echo "<a href='#'>";
foreach($FetchFoto as $autorFoto) {
    echo "<img src='".$autorFoto["foto"]."' alt='".$postagem["autor"]."' class='img-circulo'>";
}
echo "</a>";
```

Answer (score 5):

Não pode concatenar um foreach segue como deveria ficar.

```
<?php
$select = $bd -> prepare("SELECT * FROM umatabela ORDER BY id DESC");
$select -> execute();
$Fetch = $select -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$Conta = $select -> rowCount();

if($Conta) {
    foreach($Fetch as $postagem) {
        $oilUser = $postagem["sla"];

        $selectFoto = $bd -> prepare("SELECT foto FROM outratabela WHERE cond = '$oilUser' LIMIT 1");
        $selectFoto -> execute();
        $FetchFoto = $selectFoto -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $fotos = "";

        foreach ($FetchFoto as $autorFoto ) {
           $fotos .= "<img src='".$autorFoto["foto"]."' alt='".$postagem["autor"]."' class='img-circulo'>";
        }

        echo "
            <a href='#'>
                '.$fotos.'
            </a>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Só pra eu entender, qual é a diferença entre essa solução e a do @bfavaretto?

Comment: A diferença e so pela maneira de fazer as coisas eu dessa forma guardo todas as imagens do foreach na variável `$fotos` e depois do chamo a variável `$fotos` para as listar e só uma maneira que fica mais limpo o código